# vba Add Item to SortedList causes an "Automation Error"

Tags: vba, sortedlist

Why the following code causes an error: -2146233079(80131509).

```
Sub testSortedList()
    Dim list
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    list.Add 1978340499, "a"
    list.Add 1, "b"
End Sub
```

Comment: Use numbers of type integer i.e. -32767 to 32767.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They keys of the list needs to be of same data type. You add two different data types, the first is of type `Long`, the second of type `Integer` and this throws the error message *failed to compare two elements..."

Simplest work around: Append an `&` to the `1`, this will force VBA to store your constant as a `Long`:

```
list.Add 1&, "b"
```

Or use variables for your key values:

```
Dim key as Long
key = 1
list.Add key, "b"
```